# Determine OS via Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How do you determine what OS is running a Silverlight OOB application?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(VS.95).aspx) to get an [OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem(VS.95).aspx) reference.

Once you have that, look at the Platform property, which returns a [PlatformID Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88(VS.95).aspx).